# how to check the mongodb indexes for all the dbs instead of searching by collection wise?

Tags: mongodb

Is a there a way to check for indexes for all the dbs in the mongod server.
In case we have 50 collections within a single db then it will be difficult to check each collection and get indexes info.

So can anyone help me hw to know how many indexes are there in the mongo server for all dbs?

Answer (score 2):

To get count of total number of indexes in a single database:

```
db.stats()
```

If you want name of all indexes and other information as well:

```
db.getCollectionInfos()
```

If you want to do same for all the databases in a given server:

```
var listOfIndexes = [];
db = db.getSiblingDB("admin");
dbs = db.runCommand({ "listDatabases": 1 }).databases;
dbs.forEach(function(database) {
    db = db.getSiblingDB(database.name);
    listOfIndexes.push(db.getCollectionInfos());
});
print(listOfIndexes);
```

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript function to be run from Mongo Shell:

```
function getAllDbIndexesOnServer() {

    print('---- Collection Indexes of all Databases on MongoDB Server ----')

    db_names_arr = db.adminCommand( { listDatabases: 1, nameOnly: true} ).databases
    total_db_ixs = 0

    for (let db_name of db_names_arr) {
        mydb = db.getSiblingDB(db_name.name)
        mycolls = mydb.getCollectionNames()
        print('db:', mydb)
        print('collections:', mycolls)
        no_db_ixs = 0
        mycolls.forEach( mycoll => {
            no_of_ixs = db[mycoll].getIndexes().length
            no_db_ixs = no_db_ixs + no_of_ixs
            print(mycoll + "'s", 'indexes:', no_of_ixs) 
            db[mycoll].getIndexes().forEach( ix => print('      ', ix.name) ); 
        } )
        total_db_ixs = total_db_ixs + no_db_ixs
        print('Total indexes for db:', no_db_ixs)
        print('-----')
    }

    print('Total indexes on the server:', total_db_ixs)
    print(' ')
}
```

*The output:*

```
---- Collection Indexes of all Databases on MongoDB Server ----
db: admin
collections: system.version
system.version's indexes: 0
Total indexes for db: 0
-----
db: config
collections: system.sessions
system.sessions's indexes: 0
Total indexes for db: 0
-----
db: local
collections: startup_log
startup_log's indexes: 0
Total indexes for db: 0
-----
db: test
collections: collection,test,test3,test9
collection's indexes: 1
       _id_
test's indexes: 2
       _id_
       data.date_1
test3's indexes: 1
       _id_
test9's indexes: 3
       _id_
       arrayX_1_someID_1_timestamp_1
       timestamp_1
Total indexes for db: 7
-----
Total indexes on the server: 7
```

Comment: thanks for your quck help. i will check from my end.

Comment: I converted the code to a function, and the output includes the counts of indexes for each collection as well as total indexes on the server.